# Возможно ли написать такое регулярное выражение?

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Формулировка проблемы простая: на вход подается строка, состоящая из произвольных символов (кроме \n), надо определить есть ли в ней **ровно** одна открывающая скобка `(` и одна закрывающая `)`, при этом открывающая стоит перед закрывающей (не обязательно рядом). К примеру:

'qwer(qrewq)w687rwer' -> True

'qwe((rew)ewr' -> False

'sah)sf(sfd' -> False

Сделать это легко, но вопрос, можно ли использовать регулярные выражения, даже если это непродуктивно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, но **обычный цикл будет намного быстрее!**

Вот пример регулярки

```
import re

all = ['qwer(qrewq)w687rwer', 'qwe((rew)ewr', 'qwe(rew))ewr', 'sah)sf(sfd']

for i in all:
    print(re.match(r'^[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*$' , i))
```

Вывод:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='qwer(qrewq)w687rwer'>
None
None
None
```

Описание регулярки:

- в начале и конце задаем весь диапазон `^ вся строка $`

Далее проверка однотипная, что упрощает чтение самой регулярки.

- `[^()]*` проверяем что нет скобок до открывающей скобки `\(`
- `[^()]*` так же проверяем нет ли скобок внутри скобок `\( тут \)`
- `[^()]*` и наконец тем же способом проверяем нет ли скобок после `\)`